# Add Button next the create Button in odoo Tree View

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, openerp-8, odoo-view

**how to add this button in the Tree view ??**
This code in library/static/src/js/script.js

```
openerp.library = function(instance) {

    instance.web.ListView.include({
        load_list: function(data) {
            this._super(data);
            if (this.$buttons) {
                this.$buttons.find('.oe_my_button').off().click(this.proxy('do_the_job'));
            }
        },
        do_the_job: function() {

            this.do_action({
                name: _t("View name"),
                type: "ir.actions.act_window",
                res_model: "object",
                domain: [],
                views: [
                    [false, "list"],
                    [false, "tree"]
                ],
                target: 'new',
                context: {},
                view_type: 'list',
                view_mode: 'list'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This code in library/static/src/xml/library_view.xml

```
<template xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.oe_list_add" t-operation="after">
            <button t-if="widget.dataset.model == 'inventory'" class="oe_button oe_my_button oe_highlight" type="button">My Button</button>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

in my **openerp**.py

```
'qweb': ['static/src/xml/library_view.xml'],
```

Comment: what's the issue? do you have any error in inspector console? are you sure your JS is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

What about your library/static/src/js/script.js file?

Add js file in odoo backend asset template like below:-

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="work_group assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script 
            type="text/javascript" 
            src="/library/static/src/js/script.js">
        </script>

    </xpath>
</template>
```